# iOS 6 Map is using too many TCP connections?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, mapkit

I came across the famous "Too many open files" problem and tried to find out what files are opened by my app. And it seems that it's the MapKit to be blamed!

I ran my app in the iOS 6 simulator, and **turned on "Debug > Location > Freeway Drive"**. And then used `lsof -i | grep MyAppName` to get the opened TCP connections. And this is what I got:

```
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu    1u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8b239af      0t0  TCP localhost:49504->localhost:49503 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu    2u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8b239af      0t0  TCP localhost:49504->localhost:49503 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu    4u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8b239af      0t0  TCP localhost:49504->localhost:49503 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu    5u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a849b407      0t0  TCP localhost:49505->localhost:49503 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu    6u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a62634ff      0t0  TCP localhost:49506->localhost:49503 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   30u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a84350e7      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50151->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   31u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a939f407      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50148->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   32u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a939f407      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50148->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   33u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a3482f57      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50149->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   34u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a3482f57      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50149->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   35u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8540277      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50150->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   36u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8540277      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50150->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   37u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a84350e7      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50151->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   38u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a89f468f      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50157->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   39u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a89f3f57      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50152->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   40u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a89f3f57      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50152->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   41u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a75bcdc7      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50153->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   42u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a75bcdc7      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50153->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   43u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a90729af      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50154->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   44u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a90729af      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50154->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   45u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a94b2ccf      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50155->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   46u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a94b2ccf      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50155->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   47u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a4eac0e7      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50156->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   48u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a4eac0e7      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50156->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   49u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a89f468f      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50157->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   50u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a94754ff      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50167->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   51u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a849accf      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50158->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   52u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a849accf      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50158->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   53u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a76c868f      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50159->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   55u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a76c868f      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50159->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   56u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a66a1277      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50160->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   57u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a66a1277      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50160->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   58u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a93d7f57      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50161->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 36816 ivanzhu   59u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a93d7f57      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.108:50161->123.103.0.159-bj-cnc:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

And the list kept growing and growing to a point that my code started to get "Too many open files" error when trying to write a file.

And I did the same test on iOS 5.1 simulator and it looked OK (no additional connections):

```
iWasteBul 37547 ivanzhu    1u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8a00dc7      0t0  TCP localhost:51490->localhost:51489 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 37547 ivanzhu    2u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8a00dc7      0t0  TCP localhost:51490->localhost:51489 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 37547 ivanzhu    4u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8a00dc7      0t0  TCP localhost:51490->localhost:51489 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 37547 ivanzhu    5u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8a0cdc7      0t0  TCP localhost:51491->localhost:51489 (ESTABLISHED)
iWasteBul 37547 ivanzhu    6u  IPv4 0xf7ae68a3a8a014ff      0t0  TCP localhost:51492->localhost:51489 (ESTABLISHED)
```

In order to make sure it's not my app's problem, I killed all running apps in the simulator, start the built-in "Maps" app, and got the same result. But I couldn't do the same test in iOS 5.1 simulator because there's no "Maps" app installed in it.

My questions are:

1. Am I using the right tool to get opened TCP connections?
2. Is it a bug in iOS 6 simulator (and potentially device)?
3. How to deal with it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, I can tell you that it exists in iOS 6.0.1. I run a forum and several times a day, I get emails from the server's DDoS-protection module, such-and-such IP was "blocked for too many connections", 50 or more but usually close to 80.

The only common thing between these people is that they're on an iPad that runs iOS 6.0.1. I've only seen one 6.0.2 connection, so can't verify if the problem is fixed with 6.0.2.

Comment: hi James, thanks for your response. But I'm not sure if we are talking about the same problem here. The TCP connections in my post were apparently generated by the MKMapView trying to retrieve map tiles from Apple map server. If the MKMapView is removed from the app, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: The common issue is that iOS6 is opening excessive numbers of ports to the destination server, rather than 2-5 and reusing them for additional requests (following Http/1.0 instead of Http/1.1).

I don't know anyone at Apple to complain to, and a friend-of-a-friend says Apple checks here, so I hoped yours and mine were similar enough that Apple might notice and fix. :)